# Linux program running on Ubuntu machine but not on Unix webserver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

I've downloaded the command-line program "Whitaker's Words" which was available for Linux as well as Windows etc.

There is a main program named `words`. I tried to execute it on my Ubuntu (11.10) machine on command line and it worked:

```
./words
```

When I tested it on my Linux webserver (Linux 2.6.37-he-xeon-64gb+1 i686), it worked as well.

Then I decided to apply some changes to the source code and to recompile it. For that, I used the following commands (the latter four are supporting programs):

```
gnatmake -O3 words -bargs -static
gnatmake makedict -bargs -static
gnatmake makestem -bargs -static
gnatmake makeefil -bargs -static
gnatmake makeinfl -bargs -static
```

The resulting program worked properly on my Ubuntu machine again, as I could see the correct output in the terminal.

But when I tried to execute it on my webserver using PHP's `shell_exec()` or `passthru()`, there was simply no output! According to `ldd`, the program is `statically linked` so it should really work, shouldn't it?

I've been testing and debugging for weeks now and I can't find any reason why this is so. Can you help me?

You can get the program here: [download link at filedropper.com](http://www.filedropper.com/words)

(I guess this is no programming question, as my problem is just: How to get that program running on my webserver?)

**System I want to compile the program on:**

Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu x86 GNU/Linux

This is the newest Wubi (32-bit) release of Ubuntu.

`ldd --version` outputs `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-20ubuntu5) 2.13`

**System I want to run the compiled program on (webserver):**

Linux 2.6.37-he-xeon-64gb+1 i686 GNU/Linux

`ldd --version` outputs `ldd (GNU libc) 2.7`

**Note:**

Errors on the server side can be excluded as everything works fine if I just replace my own Linux program by the pre-compiled one.

**Update #1:**

I've tried running the program (that works fine under Ubuntu 11.10) in my VirtualBox under Ubuntu 5.10 - and it didn't work, either. Good news, so it's definitely not the server's fault. Ubuntu 5.10 just said: `floating point exception`. Does this help? Why is there an exception but not under Ubuntu 11.10?

**Update #2:**

Now compiled with Ubuntu 5.1 using GNAT 3.4. But all hope for nothing - still no output, `ldd` says `statically linked` (as I've compiled it that way) and `strace` gives the same error message. What does it mean? Is there any file missing? Is this the reason why it is not working?

```
execve("./words", ["./words"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x811e000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76f8000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76f7000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb76f7680, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Comment: Does program execute? Are the environment settings between your shell and shell escape from PHP the same?

Comment: It seems that the program does not execute on my webserver as I can't see any output in PHP. But on my Ubuntu machine, it does execute. How can I check if these environment settings are the same?

Comment: The weird fact is that the pre-compiled version runs on both systems but my self-compiled program does only on the Ubuntu machine, not on the webserver.

Comment: Are you unable to login to the box to execute this program on the command line? Perhaps you are forgetting to echo the output of the command (e.g. <? shell_exec('...'); ?> instead of <? echo shell_exec('...'); ?>.)

Comment: You don't specify — what flavour of UNIX is your webserver running and on what architecture?  If it's not Linux (there are many other UNIXen out there) or isn't of a compatible processor architecture, static linking doesn't help.  Also, if the webserver is running an older Linux kernel, you may need to link with an older Glibc, as the newer code might not run on it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @solo: I do output the result of `shell_exec()` via `echo` in PHP, thanks! @ephemient: I've added some details as to the systems in the question above.

Comment: I've posted some details regarding the glibc version on my two systems. As you can see in the question above, the glibc versions seem to differ from each other. Are they compatible, nevertheless, or is this what prevents the program from running on my webserver?

Comment: Try running it as `shell_exec('/path/to/your_binary 2>&1')`.

Comment: @MischaArefiev: Did that already: No output. So the problem really seems to be that the program is just not executable due to a different glibc version or processor architecture, right?

Comment: @MarcoW. Did you check that `./words` is marked executable on the server?

Comment: @ephemient: Yes, even with `CHMOD 777`, the program doesn't produce any output. What's the matter with glibc? `GNU libc 2.7` seems to be something different than `EGLIBC 2.13`, doesn't it?

Comment: [EGLIBC](http://www.eglibc.org/) is a branch of [GLIBC](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) and should not be incompatible.  Hmm, perhaps `strace` would be useful?

Comment: `execve([...] = 0 brk(0) = 0x8145000 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file...) mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb772c000 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file...) mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb772b000 set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb772b680, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) --- +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++ `

Comment: @MarcoW. Seems like the `words` is unable to initialize Thread Local Storage when starting.

Comment: If I compile this program without the `-static` and `-bargs` tags, this error message disappears. But it still cannot execute because it depends on libgnat.so then which cannot be found on the webserver. Any possibility to integrate this library into the program? The other dependencies are okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute anything as a shell escape from the webserver or any other program the environment settings quite likely don't get applied.  For example variables like: `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc have their default settings or no settings whatsoever so when you are doing the shell escape you should at least do the following:

- Call the program by full path: e.g. `/usr/local/bin/gnatmake` or `/usr/local/bin/words`
- get the output of `/usr/bin/env` to make sure that in the shell escape it has proper settings.  Check the same settings in your terminal shell.
- If you have control of the webserver try to make it execute as your UID to avoid permissions issues.
- Check which libraries are required for the program if any `ldd /usr/local/bin/words`

**ADDITIONAL POSSIBILITY**

Instead of executing the program directly use the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/profile

/usr/bin/env
pwd
./words 2>&1
```

and post the output.  This will tell you if the program executes and if it crashes.

One more thing to check is whether or not user `www-data` or whatever is running the `./words` is capable of accessing the database that `./words` needs if any.

Comment: Thank you very much! Executing `/usr/bin/env` resultet in `APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data MONIT_DATE=... MONIT_HOST=... PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin PDFLIBLICENSEFILE=/etc/pdflib/pdflib_licence _=/usr/bin/env PWD=... APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data MONIT_PROCESS_PID=0 MONIT_EVENT=Started MONIT_PROCESS_MEMORY=0 SHLVL=4 MONIT_PROCESS_CPU_PERCENT=0 MONIT_SERVICE=apache2 MONIT_PROCESS_CHILDREN=0 MONIT_DESCRIPTION=failed, cannot open a connection to INET[...] via TCP`. Full path did not change anything. `ldd` see question above.

Comment: `PWD` was `/is/htdocs/www/words` by the way, if this is important.

Comment: @MarcoW. Where is `words` program?

Comment: The PHP script is in `/` and the program `words` is in `/words/`. This is the path that `PWD` returned as well. Of course, I did `chdir('words')` in PHP to change the directory.

Comment: @MarcoW. Updated my answer.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for this script! Output: `CONSOLE=/dev/console SHELL=/bin/sh TERM=linux OLDPWD=/XXX INIT_VERSION=sysvinit-2.88 PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games PDFLIBLICENSEFILE=/etc/pdflib/pdflib_licence runlevel=2 RUNLEVEL=2 PWD=/XXX VERBOSE=no EDITOR=vim previous=N PREVLEVEL=N SHLVL=5 HOME=/ _=/usr/bin/env /XXX ./words: error while loading shared libraries: libgnat-3.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory `

Comment: Can I use `gnatlink` or so to add the missing `libgnat` to the program executable?

Comment: @MarcoW. Not sure.  You could in the same script change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:....` so that  `libgnat-3.4.so.1` is in that path and that should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Do you mean I should use a script like this? http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=366646 Where the path to the script also contains the GNAT library file? (How to get it?)

Comment: @MarcoW. Prepend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` by `export` but basically yes.  The location of the library on linux can be found by using `sudo updatedb` followed by `locate`

Comment: Sorry for all those annoying questions but: On my webserver, in the script, I have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a directory where I put the GNAT library file that I got from my Ubuntu? So search that file in Ubuntu and than copy it to some directory on the webserver and set the library path to that directory? Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: @MarcoW. No.  You do: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<PATH_WHERE_GNAT_LIBRARY_IS>`

Answer (score 2):

Try running not the program itself but a script running this program and logging it's environment and STDERR output.

You also should have peeked into your WEB server logs.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions! In my webserver's log file, there's no entry that belongs to the program. Only the call of the PHP file is mentioned. And in the error log file, there's nothing which belongs to my program as well. When I created a Python script with `#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello World\n"
import os;
os.system("./words");` and called it via PHP, it produced exactly the same results as calling the Linux program directly in PHP.

Comment: @MarcoW. So the expected "Hello World" from Python didn't work either?  Perhaps your webhost has disabled exec?

Comment: Ur script didn't verify `os.system` runs ok. You need more verbosity to resolve the issue, man.

Comment: @ephemient: Sorry, "Hello World" did work. I was just refering to the output of the Linux program. So I had "Hello World" and then no output from the Linux program. @poige: Unfortunately, I don't know any python so I don't know how to check if `os.system` works correctly. I just thought I had to use Python or some other scripting language different from PHP.

Comment: Something like this: http://codetidy.com/2467/

Comment: @poige: If I use your code, it displays the date - so it works correctly. But if I replace `/bin/date` by `./words` in the command, there's simply no output again. Not even an error message.

Comment: It means exec runs ./words ok, therefore.

Comment: So does it mean there's really no error? Maybe error reporting just doesn't work. I mean, there must be an error. Because on the Ubuntu machine, you have output in the terminal. And on the webserver, there's no output. Can someone check the program maybe? (The link is above.) I can guarantee that it's 100% virus-free ;)

Comment: Under normal circumstances there's error log of Apache. It catches every line of STDERR output. I think your problem is typical example of an issue which is much more simpler resolved, then talked about resolving. :)

Comment: As you can see, there are no errors. I can redirect the error output from stderr to stdout by using `2>&1`. This works in other cases, but for this program there ARE no errors. And no output, either. But on the Ubuntu machine, there is output. So it must be a problem of incompatibility. Or is there any mistake in this train of thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

uh... I am a super-beginner in programming, but... maybe compiling the program in the webserver? Or make a virtual machine with same configuration that you run on webserver, to compile the code there.

Because one is x86, and the other is i686, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest solution :D Thanks, in most cases it would work, I'm sure. But on my webserver (shared hosting), GNAT/GCC is not available as it is not needed on webservers in most cases. And I have no possibility to install it. So I have to compile the program elsewhere. Unfortunately.

Comment: hmmmm.. if you really can not install gcc into the webserver, maybe best solution is to simulate this: create a virtual machine on your compiler machine with a similar configuration you use on webserver, then compile the code inside virtual machine... just my 2 bits...

Comment: I am a beginner, but I try hard. =P

Comment: Yes, this is what I've just done. Please see the update in my question above. But it didn't work, either. Because there seems to be a file missing (SIGSEV - segmentation fault?). Is this the reason?

Comment: After some google I found this, maybe helps you: "_The only thing I find strange is that Ubuntu 5.10 comes with gcc 4.0 as standard while the kernel is compiled with the 3.4 which causes problems with the vmware then, just in case, I kept gcc 3.4 as well._"

Comment: I have GNAT 3.4 but GCC 4.0 - that's right. I don't know if this causes the problem. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Give a shot with the other compiler. What you will lose with a shot?